# Detect Target Framework / NuGet DLL Incompatibility Error During Build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

Is there a way to get NuGet/MSBuild to report a .csproj target framework / NuGet package DLL reference incompatibility error during build?

Consider an application with two branches:

- Trunk branch - targets .NET Framework 4.8
- Maintenance branch - targets .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Consider a NuGet package (PackageX) that is multi-targeted.  It targets netstandard2.0 and netstandard1.1.  Since the NuGet package is multi-targeted, it will have the following lib folders:

- \packages\PackageX\lib\netstandard1.1\
- \packages\PackageX\lib\netstandard2.0\

If a developer adds a reference to PackageX in the Trunk branch that targets .NET Framework 4.8, the .csproj file will reference the PackageX.dll in the directory \packages\PackageX\lib\**netstandard2.0**\.

If the developer backports his changes from the Trunk branch to the Maintenance branch, the .csproj reference to the PackageX.dll in the folder \packages\PackageX\lib\**netstandard2.0**\ gets backported. However, **this is an invalid path for the Maintenance Branch code**.  Because the Maintenance branch code targets .NET Framework 4.5.2, the correct DLL reference should be \packages\PackageX\lib\**netstandard1.1**\.

The developer almost certainly won't be aware of the NuGet DLL path reference problem mentioned above when he backports his changes.  The .csproj builds without any errors or warnings about this issue.  It's not until the Maintenance branch code is deployed to a QA server that doesn't have any .NET Framework versions > 4.5.2 installed that the problem will be detected.  The error that will be reported is:

```
FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0...
```

It *seems* like there should be some way of detecting this .csproj target framework version / NuGet lib DLL reference problem as part of the build process.  Anyone aware of any trickery that can be done to detect and report this issue?

Comment: Did your QA server  to build your project and then publish it? Did it has VS  or just Build Tool?  Also, when you migrate the project to QA server, you should downgrade your project framework version to `framework<=4.5.2`.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like there should be some way of detecting this .csproj
>   target framework version / NuGet lib DLL reference problem as part of
>   the build process. Anyone aware of any trickery that can be done to
>   detect and report this issue?

As far as l know, the msbuild task itself did not contains such function to detect the incompatibility between nuget dll and project framework version. The build process is only to detect any errors in the compiled file such as syntax.

**As a workaround**, you can add a custom target to detect the reference version of the nuget Dll and the project framework version manually.

**First**, add this under the nuget dll which you want to detect:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>...\xxxx\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
      <EMA>%(Reference.HintPath)</EMA>
    </Reference>
```

**Second**, write a custom build target to report the nuget dll and the project framework version.

```
<Target Name="Dected" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="the Nuget DLL Path is----%(Reference.EMA)----------------the project framework is $(TargetFrameworkVersion)">
    </Message>
  </Target>
```

**Update 1**

[image]

**And** you can see this info in msbuild log or Output window in VS which will help you judge if they're compatible.

Note that when you migurate the project into QA Server which suports `framework <=4.5.2`, you should downgrade the framework version of your project `<=4.5.2`.

**In addition**, to solve the issue, you can try to **restore** nuget in QA Server. If you have build tool, try `msbuild -t:store first` command line first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I don't think will work for us as we're looking for a more encompassing approach - something that will detect incompatibility issues that a developer may not know exist.  If my understanding is correct, with this approach, we would have to have the knowledge that PackageX is multi-targeted and has a potential incompatibility issue.  Some of our applications have hundreds of NuGet packages (and hundreds of C# projects), so this approach won't scale very well.

Comment: Actually,, the versions of dlls in the nuget packages are not the same as the project target framework version. Besides, msbuild did not have the job to detect the compatibility between project framework version and nuget dll version. And the error accours when you use the codes of the special versions of  dlls and it ususally 
 occurs when you debug your project. Therefore, you could manually customize a target during the build to report their versions so that you can monitor them just as l said.